DBeaver 24.0.0 export multiple queries, naming target file
I was just "upgraded" to DBeaver Community V24.0.0.  I have a script that contains multiple queries that I export to separate CSV files.  In the past, if one of my queries looked like this
--Query name
select * from table

Then the target filename when exporting would be something like "Query name_select_from_table_20240412.csv" if the naming pattern I used was ${table}${timestamp}.
In the new version, it just sets the target filename as "export_20240412.csv"
Is there any way to get back to the prior functionality?
I've tried all the different variables available and none capture the "--Query name" part of the script and inject that into the target filename.
DBeaver export/output tab

Could you share the screenshot of "OUTPUT" tap of your DATA TRANSFER parameter? To understand... when you click on EXPORT -> EXPORT TO CSV the fouth tab is "Output"

@Nifriz screenshot added to question

Seems correct. I do a test with my DBEAVER 23.3.5 and it's works. Maybe is a bug. You can report it and in the meanwhile downgrade your installation
